# FTP upload in .net — not getting correct file path in some browsers

Tags: c#, .net, upload, ftp

I'm building an application which involves writing some fields to a database, along with uploading some files from the end user to an FTP site. The file upload works fine... in IE. In Firefox and Chrome, I get an error that it can't find the file (running it in localhost at this point, haven't moved it to a dev or production environment yet).

I have tried getting the file via:

```
Server.MapPath(FileUpload1.PostedFile.Filename)
```

... which points to the folder the application is residing in.

And also:

```
Path.GetFullPath(FileUpload1.PostedFile.Filename)
```

... which points to c://Programs (x86)/... ...

I can get a file to upload properly if I get it from either folder, but nothing from anywhere else.

Any ideas on how to make this point to the right place? Or, will it actually work properly once it resides in a server environment?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

FileUpload.PostedFile.Filename works differently in each browser. in Firefox and Chrome it won't include the full path - just the file name. It depends on your customer's browser.

Answer (score 0):

```
FileUpload.PostedFile.FileName
```

This actually gives you path of the uploaded file.

But in all the newer browsers (FF 3.6 series, Chrome, IE7+) this feature has been disabled due to security reasons. Any website should not need path of a file stored in client's systems because that gives the directory structure and may expose other important things to website owner.

So in your case, the above code returned only the file name.

you can check this link, it may help you [Fileupload control - fullpath issue](http://weblogs.asp.net/ashicmahtab/archive/2009/05/20/fileupload-control-doesn-t-give-full-path-help.aspx)